Azure web job packaging with web project for .Net Framework
I have azure web jobs project and we are packaging it with web project. Web jobs and web project are targetted on .Net Framework 4.8. As desired, building web project generates zip file package along with web jobs packaged inside it.
But when I convert these projects SDK style (still targetting to .Net Framework4.8), I don't see web job packaged in zip file. I have used Upgrade-Assistant to upgrade these projects to SDK-style. I see web project is referring to Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish package but still web jobs are not getting packaged. Build logs in VisualStudio prints this statement
Target "DiscoverWebJobs" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SkipApp_DataFolder)' == 'False') was evaluated as ('' == 'False').

Hence, i setted property SkippApp_DataFolder to false. Now after setting this property it's reading webjobs-list.json but its still not packaging web jobs. Anything i am missing? Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.
Setted property SkippApp_DataFolder to false
